# Which FileVersionInfo will my program retrieve?

Tags: .net-4.0, fileversioninfo

Suppose I call `System::Diagnostics::FileVersionInfo::GetVersionInfo("foo")` on file `foo.exe`, except that `foo.exe` has multiple version infos, one that is `Japanese`, one that is `English (US)`, and another that is `Neutral`.

How do I know which version info my program will retrieve? Is there a specific behavior that .NET uses to choose the version info that has the right locale? Is this behavior dependent on the system locale or the locale of the program the method is being called from?

Answer (score -1):

I've pinpointed it to a [Windows API function called GetFileVersionInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Currently, it is querying fixed version from language neutral file
>   (exe/dll) and the non-fixed part from mui file, merges them and
>   returns to the user. If the given binary does not have a mui file then
>   behavior is as in previous version.

I'm not sure what the "previous version" is referring to, but I am assuming that the file description and such are also taken from the neutral version info.